# Removing text with command line?

Tags: perl, shell, command-line, ssh, command

I have a huge list of locations in this form in a text file:

```
ar,casa de piedra,Casa de Piedra,20,,-49.985133,-68.914673
gr,riziani,Ríziani,18,,39.5286111,20.35
mx,tenextepec,Tenextepec,30,,19.466667,-97.266667
```

Is there any way with command line to remove everything that isn't between the first and second commas?  For example, I want my list to look like this:

```
casa de piedra
riziani
tenextepec
```

Answer (score 3):

with Perl

```
perl -F/,/ -ane 'print $F[1]."\n"' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`cut(1)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/cut.html):

```
cut -d, -f2 inputfile
```

Answer (score 2):

With perl:

```
perl -pe 's/^.*?,(.*?),.*/$1/' filename
```

#### Breakdown of the above code

- `perl` - the command to use the perl programming language.
- `-pe` - flags.

  - `e` means "run this as perl code".
  - `p` means:

    1. Set `$_` to the first line of the file (given by `filename`)
    2. Run the `-e` code
    3. Print `$_`
    4. Repeat from step 1 with the next line of the file

       - what `-p` actually does behind the scenes is best explained [here](http://www.perl.com/pub/2004/08/09/commandline.html).
- `s/.*?,(.*?),.*/$1/` is a regular expression:

  - `s/pattern/replacement/` looks for `pattern` in `$_` and replaces it with `replacement`
  - `.*?` basically means "anything" (it's more complicated than that but outside the scope of this answer)
  - `,` is a comma (nothing special)
  - `()` capture whatever is in them and save it in `$1`
  - `.*` is another (slightly different) "anything" (this time it's more like "everything")
  - `$1` is what we captured with `()`
  - so the whole thing basically says to search in `$_` for:

    1. anything
    2. a comma
    3. anything (save this bit)
    4. another comma
    5. everything
  - and replace it with the bit it saved. This effectively saves the stuff between the first and second commas, deletes everything, and then puts what it saved into `$_`.
- `filename` is the name of your text file

To review, the code goes through your file line by line, applies the regular expression to extract your needed bit, and then prints it out.

If you want the result in a file, use this:

```
perl -pe 's/^.*?,(.*?),.*/$1/' filename > out.txt
```

and the result goes into a file named out.txt (that will be placed wherever your terminal is pointed to at the moment.) What this pretty much does is tell the terminal to print the command's result to a file instead of on the screen.

Also, if it isn't crucial to use the command line, you can just import into Excel (it's in CSV format) and work with it graphically.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
$ awk -F ',' '{ print $2 }' file
```